# Tiny Problem with Centering a Column Label

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

Could you tell me why is it that I can’t get in the last column to center *G'_i* above the figure 8 below?

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cccS}
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$M_i$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$m$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$G'_i$}  \\ \hline
      28,2 & 2 & 21 & 80  \\
      28,3 & 1 & 22 & 43  \\
      28,4 & 3 & 25 & 141
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

The output I want is for the numbers to be aligned over the decimal separator, so that also for tenths, hundreds etc. are properly aligned, but that the labels above are centered over the column?

Is there a prettier way to do it?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome on TeX.SE! Even if your code is pretty simple, please try to provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe) in future questions. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the `S` in your `tabular` definition with `r` to align the contents of this column to the right.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cccr}
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$M_i$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$m$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$G'_i$}  \\ \hline
      28,2 & 2 & 21 & 80  \\
      28,3 & 1 & 22 & 43  \\
      28,4 & 3 & 25 & 141
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dcolumn` also you can adjust the alignment. Now you are using `siunitx` package. See below code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cccd{3.0}}
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$M_i$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$m$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$G'_i$}  \\ \hline
      28,2 & 2 & 21 & 80  \\
      28,3 & 1 & 22 & 43  \\
      28,4 & 3 & 25 & 141
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could typeset the whole table with `S` column specifier provided by `siunitx` and specify the format for the numbers in the optional argument with `table-format`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \sisetup{table-number-alignment = center ,
    output-decimal-marker = {,}}
  \begin{tabular}{%
    @{}S[table-format=2.1]%
    S[table-format=1.0]%
    S[table-format=2.0]%
    S[table-format=3.0]@{}}
    \toprule
    {$C$} & {$M_i$} & {$m$} & {$G'_i$}  \\ \midrule
    28,2 & 2 & 21 & 80  \\
    28,3 & 1 & 22 & 43  \\
    28,4 & 3 & 25 & 141 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to centre cell contents in a `S`column is to enclose it in brackets. I took the liberty to code an improved version of your table, using `booktabs` for the horizontal line, in order to have some vertical padding around it. Also, I defined the first column to have `S` type, to ensure the vertical centring of decimal dots (it would be lost if all  elements in the column don't have the same nummber of digits).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx,  booktabs}
\usepackage[x11names,  table]{xcolor} 
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue3}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=2.1]ccS[table-format=3.0]}
      {$C$}  & $M_i$ & $m$  &{$G'_i$}  \\ \cmidrule[1.2pt](lr){1-4}
      28,2 & 2 & 21 & 80  \\
      28,3 & 1 & 22 & 43  \\
      28,4 & 3 & 25 & 141
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]